# Plotly marker and line size and color

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, jupyter-lab

I try to obtain in certain points of a linear graph, constructed with PLotly, signals defined with the marker "tirangle-up". For this purpose I have developed the following script.
My problem now is setting different colors for the line and marker, as well as increasing the size of the marker.
How can I set the size and color of the marker and the line, in the following plot constructed with Plotly?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import plotly.graph_objs as go

start ="2017-1-4"
end = date.today()
cotizaciones = pdr.DataReader("AAPL",'yahoo', start, end)
df = cotizaciones[["Close"]].reset_index() 

# Creamos la columna PuntoCritico
df.loc[:,'PuntoCritico'] = "NaN"
i = 0
while i < df.shape[0]:
    df["PuntoCritico"][i] = 1
    i += 100

# Seleccionamos filas con 1 en PuntoCritico
df_señales = df[df["PuntoCritico"] == 1]

#Construimos la gráfica
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(mode="markers", marker_symbol="triangle-up", 
                           marker_line_color="red", marker_color="blue",
                           marker_line_width=2, marker_size=15 ))

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_señales.Date, y=df_señales.Close,
                    mode='markers',marker_symbol = "triangle-up",  
                    name='señales'))
                
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.Date, y=df.Close,
                    mode='lines ',
                    name='cotizaciones'))

fig.show()
```

I will appreciate help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the size and color of the marker you can use:

```
marker=dict(size=20, color="blue")
```

and for the size and color of the line you can use:

```
line=dict(color="purple", width=10)
```

The above can be arguments to `go.Scatter`. For example:

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[1, 3, 5],
    mode="markers",
    marker_symbol="triangle-up",
    name="cotizaciones",
    marker=dict(size=20, color="blue"),
)

trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 4],
    y=[2, 4],
    mode="lines",
    name="señales",
    line=dict(color="purple", width=10),
)
```